# I can't get Python to work with mySQL

Tags: python, mysql, connection, pycharm, database-connection

Okay, so I'll preface with, 'I am new to Python'. I am using PyCharm to run this programme I am building to dump to a Database (locally hosted mySQL).

Unfortunately I am running into problems getting data into the database with Python, but I am able to insert data in SQL running through the phpMyAdmin web gui. I must be missing something obvious. I am using 'mysql.connector' addon for PyCharm. Here is the code relevant.

So, at the start I import the module? like so;

```
import mysql.connector
```

And this code is referenced inside a couple while loops;

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host ='localhost', user = 'root', passwd= '', db='weather_test01')
            c = cnx.cursor()
            c.execute("INSERT INTO 'stations' ('dtime', 'tmp', 'apptmp', 'dewpoint', 'relhum', 'delta_t', 'wind_dir', 'wind_spd_kmh', 'wind_gust_kmh', 'wind_spd_kts', 'wind_gust_kts', 'press_qnh', 'press_msl', 'rainsince9am') VALUES (dtime1, tmp1, apptmp1, dewpoint1, relhum1, delta_t1, wind_dir1, wind_spd_kmh1, wind_gust_kmh1, wind_spd_kts1, wind_gust_kts1, press_qnh1, press_msl1, rainsince9am1)")
            cnx.commit()
```

Please dont eat me alive either for the way I write, I am new :)
Other important factors;

- I was able to get it to enter data a couple times (but it came through to SQL as a NULL value. My guess is I was passing the wrong format of number? or something to do with the db Collation?)
- I have also tried this with a number of different addons for PyCharm (All of them seem to be implemented in similar ways).
- I have tried it with and without quote marks on the variable names being inserted, I have tried so much, I am at my wits end.

As for the error codes, this is what it looks like currently;

```
    C:\Users\logge\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/logge/PycharmProjects/untitled3/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/logge/PycharmProjects/untitled3/main.py", line 111, in <module>
    weather(1)
  File "C:/Users/logge/PycharmProjects/untitled3/main.py", line 101, in weather
    c.execute("INSERT INTO 'stations' ('dtime', 'tmp', 'apptmp', 'dewpoint', 'relhum', 'delta_t', 'wind_dir', 'wind_spd_kmh', 'wind_gust_kmh', 'wind_spd_kts', 'wind_gust_kts', 'press_qnh', 'press_msl', 'rainsince9am') VALUES (dtime1, tmp1, apptmp1, dewpoint1, relhum1, delta_t1, wind_dir1, wind_spd_kmh1, wind_gust_kmh1, wind_spd_kts1, wind_gust_kts1, press_qnh1, press_msl1, rainsince9am1)")
  File "C:\Users\logge\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 561, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Users\logge\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 525, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Users\logge\PycharmProjects\untitled3\venv\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 427, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''stations' ('dtime', 'tmp', 'apptmp', 'dewpoint', 'relhum', 'delta_t', 'wind_dir' at line 1

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The 'line 101' refered to in the error codes is talking about the line starting with 'c.execute... INSERT' in the second section of code I posted.

Here is the code I have also tried, just to see if I could get any results (I still get the same errors though):

```
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
import mysql.connector

dtime1 = 1
tmp1 = 5
apptmp1 = 2
dewpoint1 = 64
relhum1 = 3
delta_t1 = 4
wind_dir1 = 5
wind_spd_kmh1 = 6
wind_gust_kmh1 = 7
wind_spd_kts1 = 8
wind_gust_kts1 = 9
press_qnh1 = 10
press_msl1 = 11
rainsince9am1 =12


cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host ='localhost', user = 'root', passwd= '', db='weather_test01')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

tomorrow = datetime.now().date() + timedelta(days=1)

add_employee = ("INSERT INTO stations "
               "(dtime, tmp, apptmp, dewpoint, relhum, delta_t, wind_dir, wind_spd_kmh, wind_gust_kmh, wind_spd_kts, wind_gust_kts, press_qnh, press_msl, rainsince9am) "
               "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,)")

data_employee = (dtime1, tmp1, apptmp1, dewpoint1, relhum1, delta_t1, wind_dir1, wind_spd_kmh1, wind_gust_kmh1, wind_spd_kts1, wind_gust_kts1, press_qnh1, press_msl1, rainsince9am1)

# Insert new employee
cursor.execute(add_employee, data_employee)
emp_no = cursor.lastrowid



# Make sure data is committed to the database
cnx.commit()

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I am happy to post the entire code if required also. I just didn't want to clutter this whole thing up.

Comment: You have some syntax errors. The column names do not need quotes. Try referring to this page and see if it helps https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Comment: @TimothyWong I had read that already, but just to make sure I wen ahead and copied it directly into my PyCharm and the example code wouldnt work either. I'll put up that code quickly too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your error. You have referenced the input data to be strings (%s). But you are putting in integers (numbers).

If you want to put the numbers as strings, in the first chunk of code (yours), you need to put in `str(variable)` instead of just `variable`. In the second chunk of code (copied from MySQL), you can declare the variables as `variable = "0000"` with the quotes.

If you want to work with numbers in your code, change the table structure to be `INTEGER` or `DOUBLE` instead of `VARCHAR` or `CHAR`.

I would assume that the table is present and all fields are present as there is no error connecting to the database and finding the table.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out soon. Do you know what symbols to use for int's, float's and decimal's? I only know the one for %s strings, I thought it was just the standard place holder. How do you store a string in a VARCHAR? I thought it would do it automatically, but it wasn't able to put anything in the rows (must of which are CHAR or VARCHAR).
I have so many questions! sry

Comment: try this website. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Standard_C_Library/Functions/printf

Comment: Hey I was having at look at this and tried handing the variables, it still didnt work, and @Unutbu says "Note that the parameter markers used by mysql.connector may look the same as the %s used in Python string formatting but the relationship is only coincidental. Some database adapters like oursql and sqlite3 use ? as the parameter marker instead of %s."

Comment: Oh yes. use the "?"